# Mail address as clickable link in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using asp.net mvc with razor.

I want to have that the email address clickable.

This is the property for email address:

```
@FormGroupHelper.CreateFormGroup(Html, m => m.Naw.Email, Model.VeldInformatie)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple. Just use a data annotation:

```
public class DemoModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The only thing is now that the textbox from email looks different then the other ftexboxes